# Write-only git repository?

Tags: git

I have a situation where it would be really useful to have a "dropbox" git repository. That is, a repo that can be pushed to but not cloned or pulled from. None of the git server solutions that I have looked at (gogs, Gitlab, Atlassian Bitbucket) offer such a thing. Is there another one that I've missed? Is it even possible to have such a thing as a write-only repo? I suspect it may not be, but I haven't looked into the git push/pull protocol in detail (yet).

Comment: Why do you need so "weird" settings? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A high-security workflow, where submitted code is not allowed to move anywhere until it has been reviewed.

Comment: See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_memory_%28joke%29) for an implementation using write-only memory.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that was easy. Modifying the permissions for the `git-upload-pack` binary achieves exactly what I'm after.

Comment: So what permission did you change it to?